# How to copy Linux distribution to different machines?

Tags: linux, synchronization, distributions, software-updates

I want to be able to install a linux distribution on my home PC but also on my Laptop. Since I already setup my home PC is there any possibility I can move the OS to my Laptop without reinstalling everything.

Furthermore, is it possible to synchronize the OS afterwards? 
Would it be possible to create an kind-of own Linux distribution on a Server where I install all the Software, install it once on each Machine and make updates afterwards like any other Linux distribution to install new Software?

It would be crucial to me to have near identical OS setups and enable synchronization. Currently I sync all my important stuff via my NAS but only documents. It would be nice if I could have a similar setup of my OS.

I am currently running KDE Neon, but planning on switching to Arch to have a clean OS installed with only necessary software installed.

Comment: How about using `tar -cpf` to make a tarball of important files and copy/move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Cloning will work well, if the computers are similar enough: when the built-in linux drivers for hardware work in both computers. Otherwise, for example if you need different proprierary drivers for graphics or wifi, there can be problems.

  This can be illustrated by the method to make a [portable USB drive (pendrive or SSD) with an installed system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312).
- So you can try how it works (by cloning the system from one of the computers to the other one, or even easier, if you can move the drive from the laptop to the desktop computer and test). If successful, fine.

  If you intend to run the two computers at the same time in the same network, you should rename one of them (or if you wish, create a [master 'OEM' system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview) and make the installations complete in the separate computers in order to make them different (with different computer names and user names.
- Otherwise you had better make two separate installations and synchronize the personal data (documents, pictures, music, video clips ...) like you do now. *Maybe* you can use home partitions and synchronize the whole home partitions. *Unison* is a good tool to synchronize the data.

---

- A more portable alternative that is easy to manage is a [persistent live drive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent), but there are drawbacks,

  - cannot be fully updated & upgraded like an installed system
  - more sensitive (can be corrupted more easily), needs frequent backup
  - cannot use disk encryption

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Arch](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) on your desktop, install all apps, then clone the drive and install a cloned drive in your laptop. You will need to change the name of the laptop once the cloned drive is installed.

However,  [0xSheepdog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/62481/0xsheepdog) (Comment below) and [sudodus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516210/49368) (answer, above) are right.

Comment: This is a great answer to a question based on a poor concept/idea. Technically you can "move" an installation, but it's almost always better to do a fresh install, considering the differences in hardware that almost certainly exist.

Comment: There's nothing special about arch in that regard.